# How do I create a calendar of events?

Tags: 8, datetime

I am needing a solution to add an event to a calendar, and the events are also displayed on a web page in order of the next event.

Similar to this Wordpress plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, there is this new lightweight module to display anything you want in a Calendar View in Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_view

Based on Views, so everything is customizable.

Answer (score 6):

As it stands, there are a few options from a module perspective.

- [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar)
- [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar)
- [Calendar View](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_view)
- Google Calendar

Calendar and FullCalendar are the popular calendaring options in Drupal - neither seem to have a stable Drupal 8 release yet but their dev branches may be workable. You'd have to try, and read through their issue queue to understand where they are at functionality wise.

Calendar View is a lightweight module to display any Views results in a calendar table. Compatible with any View. Zero dependencies.

Lastly, you could iframe embed a Google Calendar onto a page. But as you may have guessed, this means events need to be managed in Google Calendar itself, unless you set up a sync from Drupal to Google Calendar.

Other than that, there are no 'ready made' modules for this yet that are stable and production ready for Drupal 8. It looks like the others only have a Drupal 7 release or have been abandoned.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So far it looks like Drupal 8 is too new, and does not have a lot of modules designed for it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal 8 [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module is working well for our sites needs. It  integrates well with views to create lists of upcoming events and add to a calendar display being delivered from a single or multiple content types.

This module has over 125,000 installs so it will be a solid platform for our site calendar.

Comment: It's still in dev only though, and a lot of people; it's unrealistic to ONLY ever use stable releases in Drupal--you'd never be able to do anything--but dev is the lowest of releases, and many (including my boss, unfortunately for me) won't accept that as a viable option.